# Cannot clip videos using FFMpeg in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am building script where I can clip videos in laravel. Here's my code:

```
public function clip($id)
    {
        $video = Video::where('id', $id)->first();

        $vid = Storage::get('public/uploads/videos/' . $video->file_name);

        $ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

        $media = \FFMpeg::open($vid);

        dd($media);

        $video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(30), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(15));

    }
```

And I have problem because there is error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProcessUtils.php line 74:
escapeshellarg(): Input string contains NULL bytes
```

I think that is in line:

```
$media = \FFMpeg::open($vid);
```

But I do not know what happened. Can you help me?

Comment: Presumably your FFmpeg wrapper needs a filename, not the raw file contents (as returned by `Storage::get`).

Comment: So what i should do here? @mario

Comment: Get the filename?